# Fill NA by last observed value from other column, modified by adding some constant

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have start of some process, end of it and process duration.

```
        process_start            process_end    hourly_process_duration
  2019-01-01 00:00:00    2019-01-01 12:00:00                         12
  2019-01-01 12:00:00    2019-01-01 13:00:00                          1
                   NA                     NA                         11
                   NA                     NA                         15 
  2019-01-02 15:00:00    2019-01-02 18:00:00                          3
```

I always have `hourly_process_duration`. Processes are continuous - when one process ends the next one begins.

I need to replace NA correctly. Like in the example:

```
        process_start            process_end    hourly_process_duration
  2019-01-01 00:00:00    2019-01-01 12:00:00                         12
  2019-01-01 12:00:00    2019-01-01 13:00:00                          1
  2019-01-01 13:00:00    2019-01-02 00:00:00                         11
  2019-01-02 00:00:00    2019-01-02 15:00:00                         15 
  2019-01-02 15:00:00    2019-01-02 18:00:00                          3
```

Comment: Try `df1 %>% mutate(process_start = coalesce(process_start, lag(process_end)), process_end = coalecse(process_end, lead(process_start))`

Comment: Will not work if you have two and more rows with NA one after another.

Comment: I just made a corrected one in the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option to fill the missing date time

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   mutate(process_start = coalesce(process_start, lag(process_end)), 
          process_end = coalesce(process_end, lead(process_start))) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(process_start, process_end), ymd_hms) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(process_start, process_end), 
     list(~ replace(., is.na(.), floor_date(.[which(is.na(.))+1], "day"))))
#        process_start         process_end hourly_process_duration
#1 2019-01-01 00:00:00 2019-01-01 12:00:00                      12
#2 2019-01-01 12:00:00 2019-01-01 13:00:00                       1
#3 2019-01-01 13:00:00 2019-01-02 00:00:00                      11
#4 2019-01-02 00:00:00 2019-01-02 15:00:00                      15
#5 2019-01-02 15:00:00 2019-01-02 18:00:00                       3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(process_start = c("2019-01-01 00:00:00", 
    "2019-01-01 12:00:00", 
NA, NA, "2019-01-02 15:00:00"), process_end = c("2019-01-01 12:00:00", 
"2019-01-01 13:00:00", NA, NA, "2019-01-02 18:00:00"), 
hourly_process_duration = c(12L, 
1L, 11L, 15L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Comment: What if you have 3 and more NA one after another?

Comment: @DmytroFedoriuk  Good question.  I would first convert the columns to Datetime, `mutate_at`  `ymd_hms`.  Then do a `group_by` on the Day `as.Date(process_start)` , make use of the `seq` with `length.out` and `by = "3 hour" from the last element of the group to fill those values

Comment: @DmytroFedoriuk  do you have cases where both 'process_start' and 'process_end' are NA for many rows (>5 adjacent rows)?

Comment: unfortunately, yes I have

Comment: I don't see any solution except loop in this case

Comment: @DmytroFedoriuk  You can still do that without a loop if the 'Date' can be correctly assigned